# Piecewise function analysis

Tags: calculus, functions

$f(x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      \frac{e^{-x}-1}{x}, & x>0 \\
      \frac{x}{2}+1, & x\leq 0 \\
\end{array} 
\right. $

**a) At which intervals are f strictly increasing and at what intervals are f strictly decreasing.**

Should I just find the derivative of both of the functions? If so, I get that the function is increasing in the intervals $(-\infty, 0)$ and $(0, \infty)$. Is this right, or can I just right $(-\infty, \infty)$?

**b) Determine any local and global extreme values for f.**

When graphing the function I don't see any local or global extreme values. The whole function is not bounded, so I can't look at the values in the endpoints. But my teacher says there are extreme values. So I'm confused

**c) Determines if f has asymptotes.**

I know there is at least one asymptote, y=0, given the first function. But I was told there is one oblique asymptote also. But how?

Answer (score 1):

a) you have seen that $f$ is increasing at $(-\infty, 0)$ and $(0, \infty)$. Now you need to see whether $f(0) > f(a)$ for $a < 0$ to conclude $f$ is strictly increasing everywhere. Hint: consider $\lim_{x \to 0+}f(x)$.

b) A local extreme value needs to satisfy $f'(a) = 0$ only if $f$ is differentiable there. $f$ is not continuous at $0$, let alone differentiable. Have a better look at $f$'s behaviour around 0.

c) What does $\frac{x}{2} + 1$ look like for $x$ very small?

Comment: b)Hmm, I don't understand fully. f'(0) will be 1/2. But what does this have to do will extreme values?
c) When x very small, x/2 +1 will be 1. But the same question: What does that mean in terms of asymptotes?

Comment: @Mathomat55 with very small I mean $x \to -\infty$. What is $f(0)$ and what is $\lim_{x \to 0+} f(x)$? It is not true that $f'(0) = 1/2$ because $f$ is not continuous, hence not differentiable in $0$.

Comment: For a small x, $\frac{x}{2} + 1$ will move towards $-\infty$. So the oblique slope is $\frac{x}{2} + 1$ ?

Comment: @Mathomat55 that's right.